# Where processing files?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

I want to add the phone to the registration form, but did not succeed. This form processing file located? I want to correct in order to add the phone and send it

Answer (score 0):

The phone number is an attribute of the customer address object.
If you want it in the register page then you need to create it as a customer attribute.

Check this tutorial:

https://www.fontis.com.au/blog/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes